# How to delete Twilio programmable video room logs?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

When we open `Monitor` tab in Twilio and select `Logs > Video Rooms` or `Insights > Video > Rooms`, we can see past logs of Twilio Programmable Video.

We want to delete all data associated with specific video room instances. But we're not able to find any API to delete them.

Does anyone know how to delete these logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time Twilio does not support deleting individual Video Room records as they do not contain any personally identifiable information (PII). All records relating to the Video room except Room stubs, these are, Room SID/name, and participant SIDs, are kept for a maximum of 30 days on the system.
With respect to Data retention policy for Video Insights, you can refer to this document - https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/troubleshooting/insights#data-retention-policy

There are other resources that you can delete, for example recordings and compositions.
When you use programmable video, your account could be billed if you are using Twilio’s storage
https://www.twilio.com/en-us/video/pricing

**Delete compositions:** https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/compositions-resource#example-delete
**Delete recordings:** https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource#delete-recording